# Strip strings in pandas columns

Tags: python, string, strip

I have a small dataframe with entries regarding motorsport balance of performance.

[image]

I try to get rid of the string after "@"

This is working fine with the code:

```
for col in df_engine.columns[1:]:
df_engine[col] = df_engine[col].str.rstrip(r"[\ \@ \d.[0-9]+]")
```

but is leaving last column unchanged, and I do not understand why.
The Ferrari column also has a NaN entry as last position, just as additional info.

[image]

Can anyone provide some help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rstrip` does not work with regex. As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html#pandas-series-str-rstrip),

> **to_strip** str or None, default None
>
> Specifying the set of characters to
> be removed. ***All combinations of this set of characters*** will be
> stripped. If None then whitespaces are removed.

```
>>> "1.76 @ 0.88".rstrip("[\ \@ \d.[0-9]+]")
'1.76 @ 0.88'
>>> "1.76 @ 0.88".rstrip("[\ \@ \d.[0-8]+]") # It's not treated as regex, instead All combinations of characters(`[\ \@ \d.[0-8]+]`) stripped
'1.76'
```

You could use the `replace` method instead.

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r"\s@\s[\d\.]+$", "", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about str.split() ?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split

The function splits a serie in dataframe columns (when expand=True) using the separator provided.

The following example split the serie df_engine[col] and produce a dataframe. The first column of the new dataframe contains values preceding the first separator char '@' found in the value

```
df_engine[col].str.split('@', expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I have really overcomplicated myself with my code.